# Why does this happen? R apply and library functions

Tags: r

Does anyone know why I do not receive output from this command:

```
library("dplyr", character = T)
```

Yet, I receive output following this command:

```
sapply("dplyr", library, character = T)
```

?

The output looks like this:

```
     dplyr      
[1,] "dplyr"    
[2,] "stats"    
[3,] "graphics" 
[4,] "grDevices"
[5,] "utils"    
[6,] "datasets" 
[7,] "methods"  
[8,] "base"
```

Comment: Because, from the docs: "Normally library returns (invisibly) the list of attached packages". The normal way of calling it suppresses the printing of that output. But not with sapply.

Comment: @joran Just saw your comment after I added an answer on this point. Will update the answer to quote the help file and credit you also

Comment: @duckmayr No need to credit me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `library()` by default *invisibly* returns the value returned by `.packages()`,<sup>1</sup> so if you call `library()`, you won't see anything. However, `sapply()` *visibly* returns **whatever** the return value of the calls are. Consider an example:

```
f <- function(x) invisible(1)
f(1)
sapply(1, f)
# [1] 1
```

<sup>1</sup> From `help("library")` (kudos to @joran for pointed out this was mentioned in the docs):

> Normally library returns (invisibly) the list of attached packages